# Extracting fields from a data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax

(I am fairly new to Haskell) I made a data type like this -

`data MatchingCondition = MatchingHead String | MatchingBody String | MatchingTail String`

Now I want to write a function `extractCondition :: MatchingCondition -> String` which extracts the string out of this data type.

One way to do this is to explicitly write

```
extractCondition (MatchingHead x) = x
extractCondition (MatchingBody x) = x
extractCondition (MatchingTail x) = x
```

Right now, the cases were few so I could easily write down this function but it would become a huge pain if there were more cases or if in future I were to add more conditions to my data type. So is there any easy way to do this.

Besides, when my friend saw this code, he commented: this seems like it is defeating the type-safety introduced by the sum-type in the first place.

Can somebody explain what does this exactly mean?

Comment: What kinds of cases do you think might be added in the future? Would all of them share the same pattern of `MatchingSomething String` or not? If so, then what people have already suggested—such as separating the `Head`/`Body`/`Tail` tag from the `String` condition—would work fine. What is the context where you want to use `extractCondition`? There may be a better way to write it, depending on the actual problem you’re trying to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would be a nice thing to be possible to write underscore for constructors:

```
extractCondition (_ x) = x
```

Unfortunately you cannot write such code in Haskell.

But you can always refactor your code to move tag into separate field:

```
data MatchingType = Head | Body | Tail
data MatchingCondition = Match MatchingType String

extractCondition (Match _ x) = x
```

There exist techniques where you just write something like `extract @String myMatching`, which will automatically return the `String` from every constructor. And you don't need to write any code at all! (see [*Scrap your boilerplate*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scrap_your_boilerplate)). Though it's probably not what you want.

The record-based solution in the other answer is also a valid solution. Though you should be careful with having records inside sum types. This can be dangerous!

Re *type-safety defeat*: better ask your friend since he said this. But it's hard to tell what he means without looking at the whole code.

Comment: This technique looks interesting. Besides, can you point out at an example where using records inside sum types is dangerous?

Comment: "The record-based solution in the other answer is also a valid solution" - Is that a better way rather than writing an `extractCondition` function separately?

Comment: @kishlaya You can see simple example about using record fields inside data types on this slide from my Haskell lecture: http://slides.com/fp-ctd/lecture-3#/19 RE record solution from another answer: it's better while all your constructors have `String` field. Writing function of type `MatchingCondition -> Maybe MyField` is a good way to go. There exist some techniques like lenses and prisms where you don't need to write those functions manually, they can be generated for you but that's another advanced topic.

Answer (score 6):

I'll only cover this point:

> Besides, when my friend saw this code, he commented: this seems like it is defeating the type-safety introduced by the sum-type in the first place.
>
> Can somebody explain what does this exactly mean?

Your friend is probably worried that in the future you will add some constructor without a `String` inside.

Consider:

```
data T = A String | B String

getString :: T -> String
getString (A s) = s
getString (B s) = s
```

There's nothing wrong with this, as long as `T` is set into stone.

If, instead, later on `T` is changed, we might end up with

```
data T = A String | B String | C NotAString

getString :: T -> String
getString (A s) = s
getString (B s) = s
getString (C n) = error "not a string, let's make the program crash!"
```

If `T` becomes extended in such way, `getString` becomes a *partial* function, which should be avoided. Having such a function around one is tempted to write code such as

```
foo :: T -> ...
foo t = use (getString t)
```

and "forget" about the non-string case, potentially crashing the program. If instead `foo` has to pattern match on all constructors, we would remember that case as well.

When `T` is extended, the type `getString :: T -> String` becomes a lie to the user. It is telling them that a `String` will always be produced but that's not the case.
Typical solutions include removing `getString` and let `foo` do all the pattern matching, or, if "most" of the cases have a string, keep `getString` but change it to `getString :: T -> Maybe String` so that `foo` now will be forced to handle the "no string" case.

I'll also mention a common design error to avoid, which is a case of "boolean blindness". Some programmers are tempted to keep `getString :: T -> String` partial, and add a helper function

```
hasString :: T -> Bool
```

with the intention of using

```
foo t = if hasString t
   then use (getString t)
   else handleNoString
```

The issue here is that the used has to remember that each `getString` call must be guarded by `hasString`. The compiler does not help the programmer of that. This puts more burden on the programmer, who has to actively avoid dangerous cases. This issue would not be there if we used `Maybe` instead.

```
foo t = case getString t of
   Just s  -> use s     -- now use (getString t) would be a type error, and rightly so!
   Nothing -> handleNoString
```

This design is present in some Java library, which probably contributed to it becoming widespread. (I was told that many Java programmers now consider it a bad design.)

Comment: Yeah, I've done some JAVA programming in the past and so I am familiar with that method (but I don't find it to be very elegant).
Although, using `Maybe` is an excellent option.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do that is using records:

```
data MatchingCondition = MatchingHead { extractCondition :: String }
                       | MatchingBody { extractCondition :: String }
                       | MatchingTail { extractCondition :: String }
```

Comment: We have just as many `extractCondition` lines as before, they're just in a different place

Comment: @luqui Yes, and does this way of writing the `MatchingCondition` data type guarantee type-safety?

Comment: @mb14 We can't omit `String`. We need to specify the type in each case.